# Use of multiple foreign_table in TCA

Tags: select, typo3-6.2.x

How could the following select usecase be realised in TCA:

I have different products tables (windows, doors, ...) in a product extension. I also have a references extension, where each reference item should contain the used products. I configured a TCA select in the references TCA. But i'm not able to get the products of these multiple tables to the select box. Is it possible to have all items of windows and all items of doors in one select box?

```
    'products' => Array (
    'label' => 'Verwendete Produkte: ',
        'config' => Array (
            'type' => 'select',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_products_windows',
            'foreign_table_where' => ' AND tx_products_windows.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            'size' => 5,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 99,
        )
    ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible in`select` type, at least is not documented.

Anyway you can achieve what's needed [`group`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group.html) type with `internal_type` = `db` - (preferably with **suggest wizard**)

```
'products' => array(
    'label' => 'Verwendete Produkte',
    'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
    'config' => array(
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'tx_products_windows,tx_products_doors',
        'MM' => 'tx_products_products_mm',
        'show_thumbs' => 1,
        'size' => 5,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 9999,
    ),
),
```

And use with it typical MM table containing tablenames field:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_foo_bar_mm (
    uid_local int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    uid_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tablenames varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

    KEY uid_local (uid_local),
    KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign),
    KEY tablenames (tablenames)
);
```

Quite other thing is that probably for Extbase you will need to create custom getter and process items *manually* (just finding them and storing in array to keep the order).